# "Clear recent history" greyed out in Ubuntu Firefox

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, history

I'm using Firefox 3.5.9 in Ubuntu 9.10. The "Clear recent history" menu item on the Tools menu is greyed out. I tried launching Firefox using sudo from the command line, but no luck. What gives?

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem here.

Comment: The FBI are onto you and have locked your browsing history for further investigation. Agents will be dispatched to recover the information shortly.

Comment: never start firefox as sudo. you will end up with a profile (and a history) in /root folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/forum/1/531448?

> Found problem. Under Privacy the box
>   was checked with Always Start Firefox
>   in a Private Browsing Session. [...] Unchecked it and the
>   tabs came back.